# Watching a variable from a service from a different Controller in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I was wondering how can you watch a variable from a service from a different controller. I have two controllers and one service. Whatever changes in the variable that controller 1 makes will be placed in the service in which Controller 2 needs to check from time to time  if there are changes in the variable inside the service. But I can't get it to watch properly. Here is my code.

Controller 1

```
 app.controller('ChooseFleetController',function($scope,shareDataService){                                   
     $scope.$watch('ItineraryDetails', function(newValue, oldValue){
         shareDataService.setData(newValue);
    }, true);
}
```

Controller 2

```
  app.controller('ItineraryReservationController',function($scope,shareDataService){
     $scope.$watch(function () {
        return shareDataService.ItineraryDetails;
     }, function (newVal) {
       console.log(newVal);
     });
});
```

SERVICE

```
app.service('shareDataService', function() {
var ItineraryDetails = {};

var setData = function(data) {
    ItineraryDetails = data;
}   

var getData = function (data) {
  return ItineraryDetails;
}

return {
    setData: setData,
    getData: getData
};
});
```

Comment: What about your code doesn't satisfy your concept?  Ideally yes, you'd be using a service to share state between two controllers; what have you encountered that's not causing it to work the way you want it to?

Comment: Yes, I cannot get the ItineraryDetails object with the updated values from Controller 2 @Makoto

Comment: What happens when you trace it?  What do you see happening in the debug window?

Comment: Nothing.. no errors. the $watch service doesn't seem to capture any changes I make inside Controller 1

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't show us a natural way to interface with either controller.  My biggest concern is the injection piece - your code will be mangled to high Heaven if it's shown an uglifier - but also, it's unclear from this snippet how to invoke one given the other.

Comment: @Makoto I think georgeawg answer was suffice :) Thanks for your help :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ItineraryDetails` is a private variable of the `shareDataService`. The watcher needs to execute the getData function.

```
app.controller('AppController2',function($scope,shareDataService){
     $scope.$watch(function () {
        //return shareDataService.ItineraryDetails;
        return shareDataService.getData();
     }, function (newVal) {
       console.log(newVal);
     });
});
```

Comment: Exactly what I am looking for! I never thought $watch could observe a function :) Thank you!!!

Comment: this is really nice

Answer (score 2):

Another solution, for this problem, that I know of is to use $rootScope.$broadcast in the Service and $scope.$on in the controllers. Here is what the code look like:

SERVICE

```
app.service('shareDataService', function($rootScope) {

    var ItineraryDetails = {};


    var setData = function(data) {
        ItineraryDetails = data;
        this.$rootScope.$broadcast('itinerary-change', data);
    }   

    var getData = function (data) {
        return ItineraryDetails;
    }

    return {
        setData: setData,
        getData: getData
    };
});
```

CTRL-1

```
app.controller('ChooseFleetController',function($scope,shareDataService){
     $scope.$on('itinerary-change', function(event, data){
           console.log(data);
           $scope.$apply(); //if you need to apply change to view immediately
     });
});
```

CTRL-2

```
app.controller('ItineraryReservationController',function($scope,shareDataService){
         $scope.$on('itinerary-change', function(event, data){
               console.log(data);
               $scope.$apply(); //if you need to apply change to view immediately
         });
    });
```

What you guys thinks about that solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can try direct `object` using `shared service`:

```
user: any = {
    "name": '',
    "role": '',
    "isActive": false
}
```

once it change, will reflect both place(**Controller**).

> But if you reload page, changes will be again default one, what you defined in shared service.

Or You can you `localstore` that depands on your requirement.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score -1):

```
    angular.module('starter.services',[])
    .factory('shareDataService',function(){
       var ItineraryDetails = {};

       var setData = function(data) {
        ItineraryDetails = data;
     }   

    var getData = function (data) {
        return ItineraryDetails;
    }

    return {
        setData: setData,
        getData: getData
    };
})
```